# Is there a way to import STL files to mesh3d in R?

Tags: r

I have an STL that I'm trying to use for the endomaker function in the Arothron library, but all the inputs require mesh3d data.

I've figured out how to read STLs using the readSTL function but there does not seem to be a way to convert the STL into a mesh3d object. It looks like the mesh3d function requires a list of vertices but I don't know how to get that from the STL format either.

Comment: `readSTL` with `plot=FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

try the Morpho R package

```
library(Morpho)
library(Arothron)
mymesh <- file2mesh("meshpath")
endocast <- endomaker(mymesh)
```